# Python Pandas Dataframe - Only first line of output gets saved in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my webscraper i get URLs from Json Data with a For Loop, then it gets assorted in a dataframe to 'Images' and then written to a csv. However both the dataframe and the csv only save the first line of the output.

Part of my Code where the for loop is:

```
images = json_data[3]["options"]["images"]
    for image in images:
        src = (image['url'])

    scraped = {
        'Images': src,
    }
    scrapedresult.append(scraped)
```

The output while debugging: https://prnt.sc/1ucgxpa (all URLs you see here belong to one row, however, only the first URL gets saved in the row of the dataframe)

What can I do so the output gets as a whole into the row of the dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Place the scrapedresult.append within the scope of the for statement like so.

images = json_data[3]["options"]["images"]
for image in images:
src = (image['url'])

```
scraped = {
    'Images': src,
}
    scrapedresult.append(scraped)
```

Comment: i did that but now the product gets copied for every image a new time like that: prnt.sc/1ucl9t2 while all images belong to same product

Comment: my goal was to save all links in one field together